# Linq object to Crystal report

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, datasource

I have a `List<Customer>` which is a linq object from a table. I want to generate a letter per customer by iterating through this list and writing a PDF to disc.

I want to use Crystal Reports, in the database expert I have chosen .Net Objects and selected my `Linq.Customer` object as the source. This shows all my fields as expected and I can create the report fine.

I am getting the exception "Data Source is not valid"

This is my code

```
public void GenerateLetters(List<Customer> customers){

      foreach(Customer cust in customers){

             this.Generate(cust);

       }

}
```

Where Generate() is:

```
public Generate(Customer cust){

            // this is the crystal reports letter
            Letter letter = new Letter();

            // set data source
            letter.SetDataSource(cust);    // exception thrown here

            // get the pdf stream
            pdfStream = (MemoryStream)letter.
                        ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);

            // copy to byte array
            fileBytes = pdfStream.ToArray();

            // clean up
            pdfStream.Close();
            letter.Dispose();


}
```

I am getting the exception on setting the Data source, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Which type of exception?

Comment: @JanP. DataSourceException - The data source object is invalid.

Comment: I'm not very familiar to Crystal but try to pass a `List<Customer>` as datasource: `letter.SetDataSource(new List<Customer>() { cust });`

Comment: @JanP. I am getting a new exception "DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>." there are some nullable fields in my Customer object, do i need to remove these?

Comment: I think the exception told us so ^_^ try it and report your succes

Comment: @JanP. Yea it worked, thanks for your help. If you post an answer I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar to Crystal but try to pass a `List<Customer>` as datasource:

```
letter.SetDataSource(new List<Customer>() { cust });
```